# Refreshing status logo in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I am trying to build a simple chat client. What I have is a UITableView with the user names and a small status image on the left in each cell. I am getting the usernames and current status (offline/online) from a server. My problem is how do I refresh my status logo? The code is pretty involving but here's the part where i am loading the images.Any help please..

```
if (indexPath.section == 1)
{   
    if([[userDetails objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"Logged Off"]) 
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"offline.png"];

    } else {

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"online.png"];
    }
}
```

P.S. it seems that there is some confusion regarding the question..I am getting the status logo to diplay just fine at the initial login..my problem is how do i refresh them as they are changed on the server

Comment: please tell me the total no of section you created or use indexPath.row. because if you create just 1 section then your if conditions will never satisfy.

Comment: there are two sections, section 0 is reserved for the user info and section 1 is for the friend list

Comment: use [tablename reloadata] when you want to change status

Answer (score 0):

try using [cell setNeedsLayout];